# Best way to handle async backend call Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I have a class called FeedbackEdit that requires data in a variable called feedback to run correctly. I must get feedback from a backend API call. Currently, the code I have runs, but it shows an error for one second while it is retrieving data from the back-end. What would be the best way to fix this so it runs continuously?

```
class FeedbackEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FeedbackEditState createState() => _FeedbackEditState();
}

class _FeedbackEditState extends State<FeedbackEdit> {
  MyFeedback feedback;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncGetFeedback();
  }

  void asyncGetFeedback() async {
    MyFeedback data = await fetchFeedback(http.Client());
    setState(() {
      feedback = data;
    });
  } 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { ...
```

Comment: Describe or display the error you are getting

Comment: The error is that the screen will go red/show an error message for one second while it is retrieving the variable data. The screen appears as normal after that.

Comment: We need the error showed on the red screen. Check your console to get what was the error.

Comment: I am assuming the error will be caused because the feedback variable which you might be using in your UI is initally set to null. It gets its value from your API after some time but till the time your API is still fetching that value, feedback variable remains null.

One thing you can do for now is give a default value tot that variable which will be over written after the API call

Answer (score 1):

it's because you are rendering your view while still fetching data from the backend. To solve the issue, you should use `FutureBuilder` ([see](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)) in your `build` method. That will make your view to wait the response being fetched from backend.

A sample code I wrote in one of my projects:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<SingleQuestion>>(
    future: retrieveFavedQuestions(questionIds),
    builder: (context, favQuestionssnapshot) {
        if (favQuestionssnapshot.connectionState == 
            ConnectionState.done) {
            if (favQuestionssnapshot.hasError) {
                // check error
                }

            if (favQuestionssnapshot.hasData) {
                // continue working with your data
            }
        }
    );
```